# conditional set in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database of funny images, but this question relates to everything with a posting date. If I am updating a page I'm first checking if there's an entry set up for today, if not I take one that has been in the database the longest, like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM amazingjokes.img WHERE listed=CURDATE()");
if(!mysql_num_rows($result)){
   $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM amazingjokes.img WHERE isnull(listed) 
                        ORDER BY  added ASC");
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $mysql_query("UPDATE amazingjokes.img SET listed=CURDATE() 
                 WHERE id=$row[id]");
}
```

Basically what this does is "get today's image and select the longest pending one when there's no image for today". Is it possible to do this in a single query and how would that be done?

Comment: Just do it in two queries.  If the first returns 0 entries make the second query.  Modern servers are so fast unless your making 10's of call to the db you don't need to worry.

Comment: Toby, although it's true that servers get faster and faster I'm an old school programmer that wants to preserve as many resources as possible. In this case I am not too worries about the server, every result is cached, so this should be called only once a day, but I can imagine other situations where speed could be an issue. I'd rather have a good programming solution than throw more hardware at a problem...

Comment: I'm old school too, but I'd rather a piece of code that is easy to read that makes it obvious where information is coming from than an overly complex SQL statement.

Comment: ...and of course comments make everything clear. With comments you don't gave to choose betwee speed for the thousands of visitors we have for the coming years and readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was one query, with a second one if there's no date set for today's image:

```
$img=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM amazingjokes.img
  WHERE listed=curdate() OR isnull(listed) 
  ORDER BY listed DESC, added ASC LIMIT 1"
));
if($img[0]["listed"]==null) 
  mysql_query("UPDATE amazingjokes.img SET listed=curdate() 
               WHERE id=".$img[0]["id"]);
```

This selects everything with no date or with today's date. the "order BY listed" makes sure that if there is an image selected for today it will be on top, the "added ASC" in the order will ensure the longest pending one is on top of the list if there's no image for today. Thanks to @Stephan for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
update amazingjokes.img 
    set listed=curdate() 
where 
    id IN (
        select 
            id 
        from 
            amazingjokes.img 
        where 
            isnull(listed) 
        order by 
            added asc
    )
```

And to replace the hole 3 queries you can try :

```
 update amazingjokes.img  
    set listed=curdate()
 where 
    id IN (
        select 
            id 
        from 
            amazingjokes.img 
        where 
            listed=curdate() 
        order by 
            added asc
    )
    AND (
        select 
            count(*) 
        from 
            amazingjokes.img 
        where 
            listed=curdate()
    ) = 0
```

Comment: every time you run this it will set today's date for the longest pending image, but I only want it to set a date for an image when there's no image already selected for today..

Comment: @patrick it was meant for this query to replace the 2 queries inside the `if`

Comment: got you! that's one query down indeed!

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to select "today's image OR the longest pending one". Then that select could go inside this update and this would be one query

Comment: @patrick you can try my latest query to see if its what you need

Comment: I think I have it: SELECT *
FROM amazingjokes.img
where listed='2013-07-02' or isnull(listed) order by listed desc, added asc limit 1

Comment: And that combined with your first post would solve it in one query!

Comment: not quite: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET (1235) - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' ;-)... lol, better install a newer version.

Comment: @patrick what ver do you have? and also pls post the full query

Answer (score 2):

If you coalesce the NULL to a value, whilst it doesn't update the source data (you probably want to do that still), you could change the select to bring back those with today's date or no date with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM amazingjokes.img 
WHERE COALESCE( listed, CURDATE() ) = CURDATE()
```